# Date time issue with `d` formatter

Tags: c#, datetime

I want to format a `DateTime` object according to a custom date string provided by the user, [which may be `d` for the day of the month without a leading zero](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
var date = DateTime.ParseExact("2016-11-05T15:30:00", "yyyy-MM-dd\\THH:mm:ss", null);
Console.WriteLine(date.ToString("d."));
Console.WriteLine(date.ToString("d"));
Console.WriteLine(date.ToString("dd."));
Console.WriteLine(date.ToString("dd"));
```

The result is standing out unexpectedly:

```
5.
11/5/2016
05.
05
```

Why doesn't this come out to `5`?
Is there a way to get `5` without making special `case` statements, and without adding other characters to every format string and stripping them away after processing (which may or may not cause errors with other format strings that I didn't check, but the user may come up with)?

Comment: A single `d` is the default format specifier for the system locale's short date format. That's why you get the date in full in your second output.

Comment: This can help you about the reason of the issue https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/az4se3k1(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"d" is the format for standard <s>time</s> date, if you want it to act as a custom format only to display the day, add a "%" to it, like this:

```
Console.WriteLine(date.ToString("%d"));
```

See: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx#dSpecifier

Comment: Standard *date* actually.

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar - True, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
string d = string.Format("{0:d }", date);
//                            ^ this space is important
// output will have a trailing space, e.g. '5 '
```

See [Using single custom format specifiers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx#UsingSingleSpecifiers)

Comment: It only add a space after `d` same thing if he do `date.toString("d ")`. OP ask for a method without making special case

Comment: True. This is sufficient so there is no confusion with the "d" default format specifier. using `"%d"` as suggested by CKII is cleaner.

Comment: What if I don't want an extra leading or trailing space?